# Java: Json has key/field

Tags: java, json

I'd like to know the most simple way to detect if a key/field exists in a JSON String.

for example:

```
if(jsonObject(myJsonString).hasKey("myKey")){

}
```

I would not prefer to write a lot. I am currently using minimal JSON and it appears it does not have such a function.

**Answer:
JSONObject jsonObj2 = new JSONObject(message);
if(jsonObj2.has("key"));**

Comment: Are you using any kind of JSON library?

Comment: Yes I am! https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json - I cannot seem to find a suitable method!

Comment: Generally speaking, you'd parse the JSON into it's "object" representation in your language, then ask for the key of interest.  Of course, this will not tell you if there is a matching key ten layers deep, but that's rarely worthwhile knowing without other contextual info.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure what you mean exactly by minimal JSON, personally I find the `org.json` package simple and straightforward (i.e. minimal overhead). It is found [here](http://json.org/java/). The `org.json.JSONObject` class, for example, contains the `public boolean has(String key)` method, which is used to check if a certain key exists.

Answer (score 2):

In [minimal-json](https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json), you'd write:

```
if (JsonObject.readFrom(myJsonString).get("myKey") != null) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
`obj.has("myKey")` was not working for minimalJson.

My solution:

Take your JsonObject obj which has that key and then do the following:

```
if(obj.get("myKey") != null)
```