# Efficiently find a key-value in JSON with JAVA

Tags: java, json, dictionary, hashmap, jackson

I want to find whether a key-value pair exists in a JSON given a key. This key-value pair may not be under root. It's possible embedded deeply in the document. For example:

```
{"Persons":[
  {"Person":
    {"name":"john"}
  }]
}
```

and I want to have something like JsonDoc.has("name"), and return true.
I search online and find this thread: [Java: Json has key/field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775291/java-json-has-key-field)

Two answers (minimal-json and org.json) both has some functioned called has() or get(), but I looked into their source code, they are both trying to find the key-value under root. So they don't meet my needs.

I can think of traversing the whole json and try to find the key-value, but it seems not efficient.

Comment: How do you expect to search the whole tree without searching the whole tree (traversing it)?

Comment: So... I'm looking for a good algorithm, or a library that has already implement some algorithm for me. Hopefully later one...

Comment: Use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Jackson, you can call `findParent` on a JsonNode which will look for a field within the node or its descendant.

http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#findParent(java.lang.String)